# view docker pyspark output files in windows directly

Tags: docker, pyspark, dockerfile, etl

Note: I am using Windows 11
I have built a docker image that executes a pyspark application to read CSV files and write them in parquet format. Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/datamechanics/spark:platform-3.2-latest

ENV PYSPARK_MAJOR_PYTHON_VERSION=3

WORKDIR /opt/application/

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY input/ input/
COPY output/ output/
COPY main.py .
```

I am using below to execute the script

```
docker run  <image_name> driver local:///opt/application/main.py
```

I am writing the output to the `output` folder. To view the output files I am  using

```
docker cp <container_name>:/opt/application/output C:/output/
```

Is there any ETL way to execute the python script(using dockerfile/shell script) and view the output files directly in windows(without copying it from the docker container)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run with a volume:

```
docker run -it -v C:\temp\csv_files:/local <image_name>...
```

Then you can write to /local for instance to write csv with pyspark

```
df.write.csv('/local/foo.csv', header=True)
```